# How to use patchelf with --set-interpreter?

Tags: linux, binary, patch, libc

I'm trying to do the following:

Change the libc of a simple test.c from the system default (Debian 9.11, libc-2.24.so) to libc 2.27.

This is my attempt:

```
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello patchelf\n");

    return 0;
}
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ gcc test.c -o test
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ ./test
hello patchelf
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd9d1d8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7ea0290000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7ea0831000)
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ patchelf --set-interpreter ./libc6-amd64_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.so test
warning: working around a Linux kernel bug by creating a hole of 2093056 bytes in ‘test’
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ ldd test
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff20b9a000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa46a35e000)
    ./libc6-amd64_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.so => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa46a900000)
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ ./test
GNU C Library (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) stable release version 2.27.
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 7.3.0.
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bugs>.
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$
```

The expected result here, is that it should run the actual program. Actual results, are that it runs the **linker itself**.

Question: **How do I need to modify my command to fix this?**

I've also tried to use libc6-amd64_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.ld instead of .so:

```
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ !gcc
gcc test.c -o test
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ patchelf --set-interpreter ./libc6-amd64_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.ld test
warning: working around a Linux kernel bug by creating a hole of 2093056 bytes in ‘test’
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ ./test
Segmentation fault
```

I've also tried to use my system default libc, and patch with that, just to establish that patchelf works at all, but again I get the same problem -- it executes the linker binary itself, instead of the test binary.

```
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ !gcc
gcc test.c -o test
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ patchelf --set-interpreter ./libc_default.so test
warning: working around a Linux kernel bug by creating a hole of 2093056 bytes in ‘test’
user@pc:~/patchelf_test$ ./test
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) stable release version 2.24, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 6.3.0 20170516.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

strace:

```
$ strace ./test
execve("./test", ["./test"], [/* 44 vars */]) = 0
write(1, "GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24"..., 616GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) stable release version 2.24, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 6.3.0 20170516.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
) = 616
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Answer (score 4):

This command makes no sense:

> `patchelf --set-interpreter ./libc6-amd64_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.so test`

`libc.so.6` and `ld-linux.so.2` are not at all the same, and you are setting `PT_INTERP` to (equivalent of) `libc.so.6`.

This command is "correct":

> `patchelf --set-interpreter ./libc6-amd64_2.27-3ubuntu1_i386.ld test`

but the result crashes most likely due to system GLIBC being a different version. As I said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617), `ld-linux` and `libc.so.6` *must* match exactly.

To make this all work, you should *get rid* of the funny `libc-amd64...` naming convention, fully extract the 2.27 build into e.g. `./libc6-amd64_2.27/` directory, then use something like:

```
patchelf --set-interpreter ./libc6-amd64_2.27/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 test
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./libc6-amd64_2.27/lib64 ./test
```